# Image does not fit properly in some mobile devices but does correctly in others

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, responsive-design

I have a very weird problem with an image (a logo) which is inserted in the header of my HTML. In desktop works properly, as well as in some mobile devices. The matter is that in my mobile it does not fit correctly for some reason I can not figure out, the image lost its proportion.

I have an iPhone, but it happens in Android too. Is weird, because locally it works fine, but once I put it in the server,  it changes its proportion, but just in some devices, not all of them.

```css
.img {
  max-width: 600px
}

@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  .img {
    max-width: 230px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5 mb-25">

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" alt="logo" class="img img-fluid">

</header>
```

Comment: What's your problem? what do you mean does not fit correctly?

Comment: specify width and height to @media .img according to size of the devices.

Comment: The fact it's working differently in different browsers is making me wonder if it's a caching problem. Have you tried a hard refresh on these different browsers, or alternatively, trying to access the site in incognito mode?

Comment: @Tzimpo Logo does not keep its proportion, it is seen kind of streched. But how I told in my description it does not happen in every device, in iPhone happens and in some android too (but in others android works fine). I encourage you to have a look by yourself, open it from your mobile: http://static.tiendanimal.es/horario-site/index.html

Thanks for helping.

Comment: @IndustryDesigns I did that, but still working in the same way. It's really curious because in my gf mobile device, the logo displays correctly (she has an android with chrome) but not in mine ( I have an iPhone with chrome and safari, both browser display the logo in the same streched way), here is the site: http://static.tiendanimal.es/horario-site/index.html

Try it! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Looks fine to me, really seems to be a caching problem!

Comment: @IndustryDesigns thanks for answer back!! Do you have Android or IOS? I am testing with people who have IOS and still keep the same problema and it is their very first visit at the web, so it can not be related with caching problem.